# ASP.NET MVC3 how to excute action method of controller using timer with interval of one hour

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, vbscript, c#-3.0, scheduled-tasks

**Hello**

i am using asp.net mvc3. i have one special controller which have one special action method. i need to   execute this action method using timer with the interval of an hour.

any best and efficient idea.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scheduling in Asp.net.What is best solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399455/scheduling-in-asp-net-what-is-best-solution)

Comment: Can you use a Windows Scheduled Task instead? ASP.NET isn't designed for this.

Comment: I agree with your second comment @jrummell but not the first. If any one searches for the keywords in this question in google, he/she will never get to the other question. You could simply answer redirecting to the other question and the question would be answered.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro, my understanding of SO is that answers that link to other answers are discouraged since that would imply that the questions are the same, even if they are worded differently.

Comment: Duplicate syndrome is the only problem with this site. Just trying to help solve it but won't be involved in an argument over it.

Comment: our main focus is to solve problem at any cost. we should focus on that.

Answer (score 3):

i am able to solve th problem using VB Script and windows schedule. please follow the following steps.

1. Make VB Script like below to call your controller action. give some name like schedule.vbs

   ```
   Call ScheduleTask() 

   Sub ScheduleTask()
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim objRequest
   Dim URL

   Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
   URL = "http://localhost/controller/action"

   objRequest.open "GET", URL , false

   objRequest.Send

   Set objRequest = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```
2. make windows schedule of "schedule.vbs" file as you want. if there is permission problem for execute schedule.vbs file, please give the required permission to it.

thanks

Comment: Thanks, i want to send sms every day. should i add a `schedule.vbs` like this code, and then add a controller/action and set my sms code in this ??

Answer (score -1):

Azure Functions to the rescue! It was designed for exactly this. You can schedule functions using a timer trigger.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview